# Caratheodory's theorem with two vectors

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

Let $S\subset \mathbb R^n$ be given.

Take $x\in conv(S)$. Then by Caratheodory's theorem, we can find $n+1$ vectors in $S$ such that $x$ is in the convex hull of these vectors, i.e., there is $S'\subset S$ with $|S'|\le n+1$ such that $x\in conv(S')$.

Now suppose we have $x,y\in conv(S)$. Then Caratheodory's theorem implies there is $S'\subset S$ with $|S'|\le 2n+2$ such that $x,y\in conv(S')$.

> My question is: can this upper bound on $|S'|$ be reduced to $2n+1$ or $2n$?

If $n=1$ then clearly $|S'|=2=2n$ suffices. For $n=2$ it seems to be the case, too (no proof).

The example in the answer to the question [Generalization of Caratheodory's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289407/generalization-of-caratheodorys-theorem)
shows that $|S'|< 2n$ is not possible in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The upper bound of $2n+2$ can be reduced.**

From Caratheodory's theorem we can find vectors $u_i,v_i$ in $S$ such that
$$x\in \text{conv}(u_1,u_2, ... u_{n+1}),$$$$y\in \text{conv}(v_1,v_2, ... v_{n+1}).$$

Consider the vectors $v_1-u_1,v_2-u_1,,...,v_{n+1}-u_1.$ These are $n+1$ vectors and so are linearly dependent. Hence there are $a_i$, not all zero, such that $\sum a_i(v_i-u_1)=0$. If  $\sum a_i=0$, then (as in the proof of Caratheodory's theorem) one of the $v_i$ is not needed for $y$ and only $2n+1$ vectors would be required. We can therefore suppose $\sum a_i \ne 0$.

We now have  $(\sum a_i)u_1- \sum a_iv_i=0$ and so there are $b_i$ such that  $\sum b_i=1$ and $u_1= \sum b_iv_i$.

Let a convex combination representing $y$ be $y= \sum c_iv_i$ (where we can assume that all $c_i$ are non-zero) and let $t$ be the least positive $\frac{c_i}{b_i}$. Then $$y=tu_1+\sum v_i(c_i-tb_i).$$

Thus $2n+1$ vectors suffice since the coefficient of one of the $v_i$ is zero.

**The 'new' upper bound of $2n+1$ can be reduced**

We can suppose that $S$ contains $2n+1$ vectors. As in the reduction from $2n+2$ we can suppose that $$x\in \text{conv}(u_1,u_2, ... u_{n+1}),$$$$y\in \text{conv}(u_1,v_2, ... v_{n+1}).$$ Let  $P$ be  $\text{conv}(S-\{u_1\})$.

If both $x$ and $y$ are in $P$ then we can simply take $S'=S-\{u_1\}$. So, without loss of generality suppose $x$ is not in $P$.

As in the reduction from $2n+2$, we can now replace one of the $u_i$s by $v_2$. We are finished unless it is $u_1$ which gets replaced. But this is impossible because $x$ is not a convex combination of vectors in $S-\{u_1\}$.

Comment: Nice argument! at the end you proved $y\in conv( u_1, v_1\dots v_n)$ if I understand the proof correctly (with $v$'s renumbered). Could we now turn around the argument to replace one of the $u_j$'s (not $u_1$!) by one of the $v_i$'s to reduce the bound from 2n+1 to 2n?

Comment: I've written the proof so it works whether or not both $x$ and $y$ are on the same side as $u_1$.

Comment: There's nothing missing - the position of $y$ did not come into the proof.  Conv(S)\P is the intersection of a convex set with a half-space (another convex set) and is therefore convex.

Comment: No it was the position of x that was used.

Comment: I reread the second part: looks ok. I think the discussion about half planes and face is not needed: just the definition of $P$, and the discussion of the cases $x,y\in P$ and $x\not\in P$ would proof the claim.

Comment: Still I think that the claim ``Then conv(S) is the union of the two convex polytopes ...'' is not true in the general case. But it seems to be not needed after all.

Comment: Your simplification seems great. This does look to be all that is necessary.

Comment: I think I've now seen what you were concerned about re. the face F. Namely that the hyperplane can contain more points of conv(S) than are in F. In that case, of course, we have at least $n+1$ points in a space of dimension $n-1$ which is just what we need for Caratheodory. However, that's an added complication which it's much better to avoid.